# How to represent objects visually?

Tags: wpf

I am wondering how to represent an object visually in WPF? For example I have a class which has a shape as a filed/property with which I want to represent the object when I add it to a panel, like a canvas for example. I know I can inherit from Shape and override the defining geometry property, but I was wondering if there was any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this...

1. If your element does not render anything, but just sits in the visual tree (for some peculier reason), then to host it in visual tree you will have to inherit it from the `Visual` class. Dont forget to override all the virtual methods from the `Visual` class to your benefit when you inherit.
2. If it needs to render on the UI (which I guess is your requirement) then it has to inherit from `UIElement` class. Here you can render it by overriding a virtual method of the `UIElement` class called `OnRender()`. This method receives a `DrawingContext` parameter that can draw shapes as you like. `Adorner`s work like this usually.
3. If you want properties such as `Style`, `DataContext` and `Tag` etc, you may have to inherit from `FrameworkElement`.
4. If you want your visual object  to contain another `Visual` object inside it then it can inherit from `FrameworkContentElement`.

Comment: Thank you, great explanation. The onRender was what I was looking for. Does the `DataTemplate` have the same effect though?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `DataTemplate` to represent your data object:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:yourObject}">
    ... your visuals
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I see. I think the only disadvantage for `DataTemplate` is that it is difficult to create in code, rather than XAML.